# What to render in the else statement of a failed .save with a partial commentform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I tried to do my best to describe my question in one sentence but it's kind of hard.

I have a story that has comments. In my story show.html.erb I load in my comments and comment form (comments/_comment_form.html.erb) and this works well. I handle posting the comments in my comments controller.

The comments textarea is required, but I have no idea what to load in the else statement of the failed .save.

I want to reload my story's show.html.erb with the form partial showing the errors.

My comment create part looks like this:

```
def create
   @comment = current_user.comments.create(comment_params)

   if @comment.save
     flash[:success] = 'Your comment was added!'
     redirect_to Story.friendly.find params[:story_id]
   else
     # what to put here to show my comment form with errors
   end
end
```

I render my commentform and comments part in my show.html.erb like so:

```
<%= render 'comments/comment_form' %>
```

If you need any more information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing you can do redirect to same page that you are doing in success case just change the flash[:error] = "your message"

Answer (score 2):

You can populate `flash` with error messages and render `edit` action (with your form) :

```
flash[:error] = @comment.errors.full_messages
render :edit
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that works for now, but I'd like to work in the same fashion as a normal form. Where I can add style and error messages per field, displaying it in a red border for example. 

In my story add form the field gets marked with the field_with_errors class etc. Isn't there a way to re-render my partial with the marked errors?

Comment: @berentrom: you can render the same partial, but fill-in fields with user input and error descriptions, you can achieve it using session. If you'd have more questions about this while implementing this approach, you better post a new question.

Comment: If I can't do it in a regular fashion I'll find out how to do it with sessions before asking a new question. It was my original question to see if I could just re-render the partial only with errors, like a normal form.